# Как получить тело документа без заголовков через fsockopen()?

Tags: php

По HTTP, кроме "тела" документа, передаются заголовки, посланные сервером через **fsockopen()**. Как можно убрать вывод заголовков вначале тела документа?

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2017 16:50:08 GMT
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
      Content-Length: 241
      Connection: keep-alive
      Keep-Alive: timeout=60
      Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32)
      <title>Передача данн...
```

Comment: Что значит убрать? Сервер всегда будет их отправлять. Можно их просто игнорировать. Между заголовками и телом всегда есть пустая строка!
Можно использовать библиотеку которая сделает это за вас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, чтоб убрать - никак. Это протокол НТТР.

Заголовки отделены от тела ответа пустой строкой `\r\n` (CRLF)

Читайте ответ сокета до первой пустой строки и игнорируйте. Потом принимайте в обработку